# How to use a POCO object to access an array of options in the appsettings.json file (ASP.NET 5)

Tags: json, asp.net-core, configuration-files, appsettings

I am using ASP.NET 5 and I want to use POCO classes to access my appsettings.json file. This file looks like this:

```
{
  "Data": {
        "ErpSystemConnection": {
            "ConnectionString": "[myConnectionString]"
        }
  },
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": false,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Verbose",
            "System": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Information"
        }
    },
    "GoogleAnalytics": {
        "Account": [
            {
                "Name": "AccountName",
                "ServiceAccountEmailAddress": "someEmail@someaccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                "KeyFileName": "key1.p12",
                "Password": "notasecret"

            },
            {
                "Name": "AnotherAccount",
                "ServiceAccountEmailAddress": "anotherEmailAccount@someotheraccount.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
                "KeyFileName": "key2.p12",
                "Password": "notasecret"

            }
        ],
        "KeyFilePath": "/googleApis/"
    }
}
```

The 'GoogleAnalytics' key contains an array of accounts that I wish to be able to access in a collection either as a list or an array. 
I created a POCO to represent this key that contains a corresponding collection of 'Account' objects:

```
public class GoogleAnalytics
{
    public Account[] Account { get; set; } = new Account[1];
    public string KeyFilePath { get; set; }

    public GoogleAnalytics()
    {

    }
}
```

And the 'Account' object:

```
public class Account
{
    private const string _applicationName = @"Storefront Analytics";
    private X509Certificate2 _certificate;
    private ServiceAccountCredential _credential;
    private AnalyticsService _service;

    #region |--Properties--|

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ServiceAccountEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string KeyFileName { get; set; }
    public string KeyFilePath { get; set; }

    public string KeyFileFullPath
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{KeyFilePath}{KeyFileName}";
        }
    }

    public X509Certificate2 Certificate
    {
        get
        {
            if(_certificate == null)
            {
                ConfigureInstance();
            }

            return _certificate;
        }
        set
        {
            _certificate = value;
        }
    }

    public ServiceAccountCredential Credential
    {
        get
        {
            if (_credential == null)
            {
                ConfigureInstance();
            }

            return _credential;
        }
        set
        {
            _credential = value;
        }
    }

    public AnalyticsService Service
    {
        get
        {
            if (_service == null)
            {
                ConfigureInstance();
            }

            return _service;
        }
        set
        {
            _service = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region |--Constructors--|

    public Account()
    {

    }

    public Account(string password, string keyFileName, 
       string keyFilePath, 
       string serviceAccountEmailAddress, string accountName)
    {
        //TODO: Validate parameters

        Password = password;
        KeyFileName = keyFileName;
        KeyFilePath = keyFilePath;
        ServiceAccountEmailAddress = serviceAccountEmailAddress;
        Name = accountName;
    }

    #endregion

    private void ConfigureInstance()
    {
        Certificate = new X509Certificate2(KeyFileFullPath, Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        Credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(ServiceAccountEmailAddress)
        {
            Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics }
        });

        Service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
            ApplicationName = _applicationName
        });
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsController : Controller
{
    #region |--Properties--|

    [FromServices]
    private IGoogleAnalyticsRepository _repo { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public GoogleAnalyticsController(IOptions<GoogleAnalytics> options)
    {
        var temp = options.Value;
    }
}
```

The 'KeyFilePath' property is properly set in the IOptions instance.
[image]

**The problem I am having is that the Account array contains null references - none of the accounts are being instantiated. I wondering if I am doing this wrong, or the Options Model doesn't support this type of behavior at this time?**

### Update in response to Shaun Luttin's answer

I implemented the changes listing in Shaun Luttin's answer. There seems to have been an additional problem. For whatever reason, all of the Account instances' properties were null until I simplified the class as follows:

```
public class Account
{

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ServiceAccountEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string KeyFileName { get; set; }
    public string KeyFilePath { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `options` object?

Comment: In my controller. I've added the controller code above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Short Answer

> I wondering if I am doing this wrong, or the Options Model doesn't support this type of behavior at this time?

**You are doing one thing wrong.** The Options Model does support arrays. You need NOT to initialize your array property with an array of size `[1]`.

```
public Account[] Account { get; set; } = new Account[1];     // wrong
public Account[] Account { get; set; }                       // right
```

## Demo

Here is a sample, just for you, that you can find [here on GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/asp-net-core-vnow/tree/master/App03Options).

**MyOptions.cs**

```
namespace OptionsExample
{
    public class MyObj
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyOptions
    {
        public string Option1 { get; set; }

        public string[] Option2 { get; set; }

        public MyObj[] MyObj { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
namespace OptionsExample
{
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.OptionsModel;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfigurationRoot Config { get; set; }
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            Config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("myoptions.json").Build();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<MyOptions>(Config);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
            IOptions<MyOptions> opts)
        {
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var message = string.Join(",", opts.Value.MyObj.Select(a => a.Name));
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(message);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**myoptions.json**

```
{
    "option1": "option1val",
    "option2": [
        "option2val1",
        "option2val2",
        "option2val3"
    ],
    "MyObj": [
        {
            "Name": "MyObj1"
        },
        {
            "Name": "MyObj2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**project.json** dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
}
```

**Output**

[image: All options are present.]

Comment: For some reason I also had to simplify my Account class. I could see that the configuration created two Account instances, but all of the properties were null. Once I simplified the Account class the properties initialized as expected. This doesn't make any sense to me. Please see my update.

Comment: @AperioOculus I have not been able to replicate your other challenge. For me, with both a complex and a simple class the options object populates properly.

Comment: You tried it with Account class definition that I posted?

Comment: I did not try it with the entire class, because I am missing some dependencies that you are using. Your class is complex and relies on other classes such as `ServiceAccountCredential` which, honestly, I lack the time to resolve.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much for taking the time to work through this with me!

Comment: You're welcome. :) If you figure out the additional complexity, please let me know.